# How to set the colors for individual labels in a legend (jqplot)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am using jqplot to plot a chart on a page. I am plotting multiple lines and I need to display a legend which will help identify the lines.

The lines have different colors, so I need to find a way of setting the coklor of individual labels displayed in the legend.

```
  var plot3 = jQuery.jqplot('div1', [data1, data2, data3, data4],
    {
      // Series options are specified as an array of objects, one object
      // for each series.
      series:[
          {
            color: '#FF0000',
            // Change our line width and use a diamond shaped marker.
            lineWidth:2,
            markerOptions: { style:'diamond' }
          },
          {
            color: '#00FF00',
            // Don't show a line, just show markers.
            // Make the markers 7 pixels with an 'x' style
            showLine:false,
            markerOptions: { size: 7, style:"x" }
          },
          {
            color: '#0000FF',
            // Use (open) circular markers.
            markerOptions: { style:"circle" }
          },
          {
            color: '#F0000F',
            // Use a thicker, 5 pixel line and 10 pixel
            // filled square markers.
            lineWidth:5,
            markerOptions: { style:"filledSquare", size:10 }
          }
      ],

legend:{
           renderer: jQuery.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
           show: true,
           labels: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4']
        }
    }
```

**[Edit]**

I have removed the previous code - as it was a red herring. I have also changed the title to reflect the new way I am trying to solve the problem, after struggling with it for days.

Answer (score 5):

After legend, please add it like this:

```
legend: {show: true } , 
series:[{label:'BANANA'}, {label:'ORANGE'}  ],
```

This will give you legend name.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the color on the series and on the legend by using `seriesColors` as follows:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart', [data1, data2], {
legend: {
    show: true
},
seriesColors: ['red', 'blue']
});
```